# How do I make Json objects to work concurrently? Python

Tags: python, json, multithreading, concurrency

What I was planning to do is to have a multiple JSON objects, for example:

```
{
    "Profiles": {
        "profile_0": {
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
            "Color": "Red",
            "house_number": "123",
            "year": "2017"
        },
        "profile_1": {
            "Url": "Myasdwfaesite.se",
            "My-Note": "aasfase",
            "Email": "fasfsef@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "5634543",
            "postal_code": "123445",
            "given_name": "Balling",
            "Last_name": "Calling",
            "street_address": "qwertr 123",
            "city": "London",
            "country": "UK",
            "phone": "65412331",
            "Color": "Blue",
            "house_number": "321",
            "year": "2018"
        }

        #Profile_2 etc etc
    }
}
```

and my plan is to make the json profile/objects to work concurrently through my code.

1. Use the profiles, between 0 - x
2. concurrently it with my code
3. When finished - exit

A more visual representation:

[image: My Thought]

*What I have done so far*

I can read one JSON object at this moment with this code:

```
with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)
```

Which gives me this output: If the first Json profile and it cant be a added another profile inside the Json else the code will not recoinze it.

An example for code that can be made out of this

```
            "Url": "Myownwebsite.se",
            "My-Note": "Helloworld",
            "Email": "Stackoverflow@gmail.com"
            "PersonNumber": "1234543",
            "postal_code": "54123",
            "given_name": "World",
            "Last_name": "Hellow",
            "street_address": "helloworld 123",
            "city": "Stockholm",
            "country": "Sweden",
            "phone": "123456789",
```

^ This is from my code on below.

*What I expect to happened*...

Is that inside the code where we have those information such as Name, Lastname, email and all that. To take from Json profiles the information, Load it into the code, Do the rest and then exit. All that should work concurrently which means When I run the program, It looks how many profiles there is and then exceute it in my code concurrently and then when all finish then quit. So that mean that profile1 should not mix exemple with profile2. All are for their each and should be the same way threated like the other.

**CODE**

```
    with open('profileMulti.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as json_data:
    config = json.load(json_data)

NameUrl = config["Url"]

myNote = config["My-Note"]

def checkoutNames(NameUrl, nameID):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......
    headers = {
        'Referer': '',
        'Content-Type': ''
    }
    payload = {
        "shared": {
            "challenge": {
                "email": config["Email"],
                "PersonNumber": config["PersonNumber"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                  "given_name": config["Name"],
                "Last_name": config["LastName"],

                "street_address": config["Address"],
                "postal_code": config["ZipCode"],
                "city": config["City"],
                "country": config["Country"],
                "email": config["Email"],
                "phone": config["Phone"],
            }

def checkoutNotes(NamesUrl, NamesPost):

#Request & other codes - Removed to recude the code
#......
#......

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': NameUrl,
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    payloadInfo = {
        "Information": {
            "Color": config["Color"],
            "house_number": config["houseNumber"],
            "year": config["Year"]
      }
    }    
def wipe():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def main():
    time.sleep(1)

    FindName(myNote)

if _name_ == '_main_':
    try: {
        main()
    }
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wipe()
```

So the dream for me is to make it to work... Basically as we can see in the code it starts already with nameUrl and myNote where I need to take that information from those json objects seperetely (concurrently).

As se can also see there is different functions where it needs the informations from Json. Exemple can be inside the function `CheckoutNames` and there is a Payload where I need to enter the Json profiles concurrently... and it should work concurrently sepereted for every profile so basically profile_0 can NOT mix with profile_1 and etc etc.. I hope I have explained well enough to know what the issue is.

EDIT:

I assume running them concurrently will be needed to run multiprocess so that every profile run on their own thread without causing any iteration between each profile?

Comment: You probably should use a database, not a JSON file.

Comment: Oh. It is not that complicated enough to need to use a database. I was planning to have maybe between 1-50 objects/profiles only :) @Barmar

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: @IrmendeJong 3.6 :)

Comment: Great! I don't have much time now to write a full fledged answer but I suggest you have a look at the ``concurrent.futures`` from the standard library. It provides very high level concurrency abstractions, especially ``map`` looks to me to be the thing you should be using

Comment: Oh I have been looking into it but I don't understand alot of it since im kinda new into this :( But if you have a spare time anytime. Please feel free to help me out!  @IrmendeJong

Comment: Anyone?????????

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Have a look at this example for inspiration perhaps https://pymotw.com/3/concurrent.futures/#using-map-with-a-basic-thread-pool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155110/discussion-between-weinthis-and-irmen-de-jong).

Comment: @IrmendeJong Yes I do have. I can add it here but I was thinking to heading to chat to not spam out here before the answers if you have any time?